# Conectar SQL server com PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

Estou tentando conectar um SQLServer 2012 utilizando php 5.3  com o driver `sqlsrv`, entretanto mesmo conseguindo conectar com SQL management studio pelo php sempre me retornar o erro

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Falha de logon do usuário 'sa'.

Código:

```
sqlsrv_connect('DANIEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS', array(
    'UID' => 'sa',
    'PWD' => '123456',
    'Database' => 'CTe'
));
var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
```

E a saída é sempre isso

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '28000' (length=5)
      'SQLSTATE' => string '28000' (length=5)
      1 => int 18456
      'code' => int 18456
      2 => string '[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Falha de logon do usuário 'sa'.' (length=85)
      'message' => string '[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Falha de logon do usuário 'sa'.' (length=85)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '42000' (length=5)
      'SQLSTATE' => string '42000' (length=5)
      1 => int 4060
      'code' => int 4060
      2 => string '[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Não é possível abrir o banco de dados "Phoros_CTe" solicitado pelo logon. Falha de logon.' (length=143)
      'message' => string '[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Não é possível abrir o banco de dados "Phoros_CTe" solicitado pelo logon. Falha de logon.' (length=143)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '28000' (length=5)
      'SQLSTATE' => string '28000' (length=5)
      1 => int 18456
      'code' => int 18456
      2 => string '[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Falha de logon do usuário 'sa'.' (length=85)
      'message' => string '[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Falha de logon do usuário 'sa'.' (length=85)
  3 => 
    array
      0 => string '42000' (length=5)
      'SQLSTATE' => string '42000' (length=5)
      1 => int 4060
      'code' => int 4060
      2 => string '[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Não é possível abrir o banco de dados "CTe" solicitado pelo logon. Falha de logon.' (length=143)
      'message' => string '[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Não é possível abrir o banco de dados "CTe" solicitado pelo logon. Falha de logon.' (length=143)
```

Comment: Por padrão o SQL Server desabilita o usuário `sa` e somente a autenticação por contas de usuários Windows é habilitado. Certeza que: O usuário está habilitado? Você não está utilizando o SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) no modo de autenticação do Windows? O tipo de autenticação do servidor está setado como `mixed`?

Comment: Entendo que este deve ser o seu ambiente dev. No ambiente de produção **não** utilize o usuário `sa`. Ele é equivalente ao `root` do MySQL e isso é uma imensa brecha de segurança em sua aplicação!

Comment: o usuário sa esta habilitado e o modo de autenticação esta mixed.

Comment: @gmsantos, por quê?

Comment: @Patrick alguns riscos são: exposição da autenticação do usuário com **todos** os privilégios na instância do SQL Server, acesso a informações indevidas, perda de rastreabilidade (quem vez o que?) . Suponha que sua aplicação tenha uma brecha de SQL Injection, o que você acha que pode causar mais impacto: uma credencial somente com as permissões necessária em um schema/banco de dados específico, ou o usuário que pode fazer tudo na instância do banco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$server = 'DANIEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS';
$port = '1443'; // porta padrão
$server = $port !== '1443' && is_string($port) ? $server .= ", $port": $server;
$database = 'CTe';
$user = 'sa';
$pass = '123456';

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, array('Database' => $database, 'UID' => $user, 'PWD' => $pass));

if($conn)
{
  // Sucesso ao se conectar
}
else
{
  // Falha ao se conectar
  echo "A conexão foi estabelecida.<br/>";
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

// Caso não conecte, verifique se as informações: nome do servido, usuário, senha e

Comment: Pouco provável que o problema seja a porta de conexão.

Comment: Te agradeço a ajuda, mas isso é a mesma coisa q eu fiz, só tu deu uma organizada, e eu coloquei só isso q não funciona, usuário e senha estão certos eu uso ele e conecto normal pelo SSMS