# conectar o Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio com o dreamweaver

Tags: php, sql-server, dreamweaver

Tenho um servidor no meu computador, o Xampp e está funcionando OK. A minha dúvida é: como eu faço a ligação do SQL Server com o meu documento html ou PHP? Eu utilizo o Dreamweaver, é o mesmo processo para conectar os servidor de testes ou é só linkar mesmo?

Esse código é o que eu coloco no PHP correto? É só isso?

```
sqlsrv_connect('DANIEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS', array(
    'UID' => 'sa',
    'PWD' => '123456',
    'Database' => 'CTe'
));
var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
```

Comment: o dreamweaver é apenas a ferramenta pra vc desenvolver, ele não irá se conectar com o SQL Server. Você terá que fazer a conexão com o banco pelo php. Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26374/69359

Comment: Verifique na documentação, possui exemplos funcionais: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: as nossa dúvidas são no mesmo contexto, porém distintas, eles está buscando um erro na conexão dele, eu nao sei como conectar, essa é a minha dúvida, como eu conecto, com um script simples ou como, não sei como começar essa conexão...